# Problems with hr in sticky footer

Tags: html, css, footer, padding

URL: http://ruslanchik.ru/go

Greetings, I faced with difficulties when I tried to stick my footer to the bottom of the page:

```
<hr>
```

appears 1% left indented and 0% right indented (*adding bottom:0px;width:100%;position:fixed;*) while it's clearly stated in css that:

```
margin:0 1% 0 1%;
```

Full style of footer div:

```
#copyright {
margin:0 1% 0 1%;
font-size:85%;
line-height:130%;
}
```

*What I need*: sticked footer to the bottom with 1% of padding on left and 1% of padding on right for:

```
<hr>
```

Great thanks.

Comment: you have put in a margin instead of padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like suggestion: 
`<hr class="hr">`
 and in your css: 
`.hr{ position: fixed; left: 1%; width: 98%; }`